# How do I render all the objects of a child model belonging to a particular object of the parent model on click?

Tags: django

Suppose there are two models `Lists` and `Tasks` where 'Lists' have one-to-many relationship with 'Tasks'.

All the objects of the Lists model are rendered on the page like this:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="grid-container">
{% for list in lists %}                 <!--lists is context for Lists.objects.all() -->
    <div class="grid-item" id="{{ list.id }}" onclick="showTasks( {{ list.id }} )">
    {{ list.name }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<dialog id="tasks">

</dialog>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
<script>
function showTasks(listid){
        document.getElementById("tasks").show();
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to render all the `tasks_set` (all the objects of 'Tasks') related to a particular object of 'Lists' in that dialog with `id="tasks"`.

As it can be seen in the above snippet, I thought of doing it by passing `list.id` as a parameter to the JavaScript function but couldn't figure out beyond it. How can I achieve it?

Comment: First you need a view that renders all the tasks for a list, then you need to call that view with AJAX in your showTasks function, then put the result of that call in the container

Comment: Can you please write that as an answer with some code for reference so that I can upvote it? @Iain Shelvington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Building on Iain's comment some code. I think it is easiest if you use jQuery so load it in the  section of your html template, e.g.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you need a view that returns the required tasks data

```
def tasks_view(request):

    list_id = request.GET.get('listid') # fetch the id of the list
    tasks = Lists.objects.get(pk=list_id).tasks.all() # get your tasks

    data = {'tasks': render_to_string('tasks.html', {'tasks': tasks})} # pre render the data

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

A remark about the view: You can of course also return the raw Json data. However, in your case I think it is easier to create a small sub-template (tasks.html in the example) and use `render_to_string` to get the html code you can simply add to your base html page. Don't forget to add the view to your urls.

An example task.html just for the completeness:

```
<ul>
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <li>{{ task }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Then send an Ajax request to the view (tasks_view) when clicked.

```
<script>

    function showTasks(listid){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/tasks/',       // url of the view created above
            data: {
                'listid': listid  // Your list id
            },
            data_type: 'html',    // as we are receiving a html template
            success: function(data){
                $('#tasks').append(data.tasks); // append the html code to the dialog
                $('#tasks').show();
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

**Solution 2**

In case you do not want to use Ajax and do not mind rendering all your tasks on loading the template you can also create a  for the tasks of each list and show them on demand. For this iterate through your lists:

```
{% for list in lists %}
    <dialog id="list-{{ list.id }}">
        <ul>
            {% for task in list.tasks.all %}
            <li>{{ task }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </dialog>

{% endfor %}
```

As you can see you can access the m2m field 'tasks' of each `Lists` object with `list.tasks.all` (no `()`!). And each  has got an individual id.

And then just show and hide the dialogs (just as an example w/o jQuery in case you are reluctant to use it):

```
<script>
        function showTasks(listid){
            // Close all dialogs
            var all_dialogs = document.getElementsByTagName('dialog');
            for (i = 0; i < all_dialogs.length; i++){
                all_dialogs[i].removeAttribute('open');
            }
            // Open the required dialog
            var dialog = document.getElementById("list-" + listid);
            dialog.setAttribute('open','open');

        };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris! Although I was looking for something even simpler with just Django and pure JS as I haven't worked with JSON and AJAX before, I will mark the answer as accepted if nothing better comes in a day or two.

Comment: @Neeraj Kumar OK, thought you wanted to follow the Ajax route. Added an alternative solution without Ajax

Comment: Thanks Chris! Ultimately I did something similar to what you have proposed in solution 2 :) That being said, I also explored another way where I just created a parameterized view for showing tasks and redirect to it on click by substituting a paramater from JavaScript function in the url like this : ```function showTasks(listid){  var url="task_view/any".replace('any', listid);    location.replace(url);  }``` Though I didn't go with this in the end.